# (JS) intanceof and window

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, window, instanceof

Last Chrome:

```
window instanceof window.frames[0].window.Window //false
```

Last Firefox:

```
window instanceof window.frames[0].window.Window //true
```

**Who does it correctly?**

*From one side: top and frame have different context according to specs.*
*But: if all windows(and frames) are instance of Window, should all of them have same contractor?*
*Confused.*